# Make a function available for all codes

Tags: python, function

I recently found a very useful function published in [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/kabure/eda-feat-engineering-encode-conquer). This provides a summary of all columns of a dataframe.

```
def resumetable(df):
    print(f"Dataset Shape: {df.shape}")
    summary = pd.DataFrame(df.dtypes,columns=['dtypes'])
    summary = summary.reset_index()
    summary['Name'] = summary['index']
    summary = summary[['Name','dtypes']]
    summary['Missing'] = df.isnull().sum().values    
    summary['Uniques'] = df.nunique().values
    summary['First Value'] = df.loc[0].values
    summary['Second Value'] = df.loc[1].values
    summary['Third Value'] = df.loc[2].values

    for name in summary['Name'].value_counts().index:
        summary.loc[summary['Name'] == name, 'Entropy'] = round(stats.entropy(df[name].value_counts(normalize=True), base=2),2) 

    return summary
```

I like to use this function in ALL the codes I write. How can I achieve this without writing the above function in all the codes.

I vaguely know that this function should be inside a code with .py extension and placed inside appropriate directory. But don't know the correct details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put that in a file somewhere (e.g `/home/user/lib/kaggle.py`) and add an enviroment variable by calling `export PYTHONPATH=/home/user/lib/`. Then you can import that function with `from kaggle import resumetable` (assuming you don't have any other module with the name `kaggle`)

Note that calling `export` will expire the variable after the shell is closed, so if you want to keep it you can add `export PYTHONPATH=/home/user/lib/` to the file at `~/.profile` and then call `source ~/.profile`

Answer (score 1):

Save the function in a `.py` file in a certain directory. Eg. `resume.py`
To use it in another file